# Whats the best way to handle a Generic param?

Tags: c#, generics

If I wanted to create an Init() method that accepted any kind of type as a parameter using generics, do I need to do an explicit conversion for every different type that I would like to deal with inside the body of that method ...

Would this be correct? And if it is, does it have any implication?

```
void Init<T>(T initParam)
{
   var enemy = initParam as Enemy;
   Console.WriteLine(enemy.ToString());
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have several type of enemies that implement an interface IEnemy, I was thinking that interface could have one single Init() method and in that way I could implement the Init() logic on each IEnemy implementation differently and with different type of params:

```
class SuperEnemy: IEnemy
{
   public void Init<T>(T enemyParams)
   {
       // In this case I need EnemySuperPowers 
       var superPowers = enemyParams as EnemySuperPowers;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit more. For example, are you looking to initialize a subset of types, or any time (like an int or string) ?

Comment: It depends what you need to do, no need to use generics with the example you have given, you could just pass `object`.  Generics would come in handy if your `Init` function did some common logic against an interface - using generic type constraints for example.

Comment: @Oliver You wouldn't even need generics then. Just accept an interface instead of a concrete type, no generics required.

Comment: "do I need to do an explicit conversion for every different type " That sounds like a bad fit for generics. Either you **have** a generic function that works on *any* type, or you should have a concrete method for every possible type. Having a single method that claims to handle everything, while in fact it can handle only a few certain types, isn´t very *generic*.

Comment: @mason I guess it depends on the scenario, but I agree, with the example posted here it would be pointless!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, generics is called generics because it means that the implentation is *generic*. That means that when you see a method:

```
void Foo<T>(T t) { ... }
```

Generics is correctly used if the implementation of `Foo` does not care at all about what `T` really is (there are exceptions but the general rule applies almost always).

If on the other hand, inside `Foo` you need to act differently depending on what `T` really is then generics is not the way to go, you'd be better off overloading:

```
void Foo(Enemy enemy) { ... }
void Foo(Neutral neutral) { ... }
//etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. I hadn't fully understood the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your update made it clear why you think you need generics, and indeed, you´re on a good track.

But instead of making the **method** generic, you can make the **interface** generic to indicate different types of `Power`:

```
interface IEnemy<TPower> where TPower : Power
{
    void Init(TPower param);
}
```

with that your class `SuperEnemy` implements that interface with a generic parameter of `EnemySuperPower`:

```
class SuperEnemy : IEnemy<EnemySuperPowers>
{
    public void Init(EnemySuperPowers enemyParams)
    {
        // now you don´t need to cast anymore, because param already is of the type
        EnemySuperPowers superPowers = enemyParams;
    }
}
```

while another enemy can have this:

```
class ApocalypticEnemy : IEnemy<DestroyWorldPower>
{
    public void Init(DestroyWorldPower param) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I think you should read Eric Lippert's series [Wizards and Warriros](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/). This set up is a splitting headache later on...

Answer (score -3):

> do I need to do an explicit conversion for every different type that I would like to deal with inside the body

Yes.

The idiom for this in C# is the [Type Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern):

```
void Init<T>(T initParam)
{
   if (initParam is Enemy enemy)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(enemy.ToString());
   }
   //. . .
}
```

Comment: Why bother even making it generic?

Comment: how does this answer "do I need to do an explicit conversion for every different type"?

Comment: @BradleyUffner no idea.  Perhaps it's simply constrained as `new()`, or somesuch.  But the answer to that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Or perhaps Ts are value types, and need to be passed on the stack.